# How do I make a TimeSeriesDrop[] function, similar to TimeSeriesInsert[]?

Tags: time-series

From the documentation, `TimeSeriesInsert[ts, {"January 1st, 2013", 900}]` is clean and easy.  How to I make a `TimeSeriesDrop` function, e.g. `TimeSeriesDrop[ts, {"January 1st, 2013"}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at code from helper functions in the `` RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump` ``  context which are implemented in top-level code, and particularly looking at the implementation of the promisingly-named `` RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`iTDDropTimes ``, I learned that `TimeSeries` objects have `"Take"`, `"Drop"`, and `"Part"` properties (or "methods" perhaps?), even though those are not documented (at least as far as I know).

Let's first have a time series to play with:

```
ts = TimeSeries@ Transpose@ {DateRange[{2021, 1, 1}, {2021, 1, 6}], Range[6]};
```

Then, inspired by the implementation of `` RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`iTDDropTimes ``, and conforming to your syntax preference, here is my quick idea:

```
ClearAll[timeSeriesDrop]
timeSeriesDrop[ts_TemporalData, {drop_}] := 
 ts["Part", 1, {Complement[ts["Times"], {AbsoluteTime@DateObject@drop}]}]
```

In the code above, the $1$ argument after "Part" selects which path in a TemporalData object the operation applies to. Since `TimeSeries` is effectively a single-path `TemporalData` object, that is set to 1 here to refer to the first (and only) path in a `TimeSeries`.

We can use the function as follows:

```
timeSeriesDrop[ts, {"January 2, 2021"}]
timeSeriesDrop[ts, {"January 2, 2021"}]["DatePath"]
```

[image: TimeSeries result which shows FIVE data points, i.e. one less than the original]
[image: the dates remaining in the time series, showing that Jan 2nd was removed]

As you can see from the date path above, the January 2nd date was removed from the time series `ts`, as requested.

This is a rather incomplete implementation; one would want to 1. expand this to handle `DateObject` input; 2. perhaps most pressing, expand this to handle *lists* of drop dates. Alternatively, it should also be possible to coax `` RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`iTDDropTimes `` into service after some modifications.

---

For the record, here's how my search unfolded. `ClearAttributes[TimeSeriesInsert, ReadProtected]; ??TimeSeriesInsert` revealed the existence of `` TemporalData`Utilities`TDDropTimes `` . Doing the same to the latter function revealed its implementation function, `` RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`iTDDropTimes `` , which, luckily, is implemented in readable top-level code. It's in that code that I found the "Part", "Take", "Drop" properties. After that, it was a question of some trial and error to figure out how to use the "Part" method.

Comment: Wow!  How did you know about that function. I propose that a Kevin Mitnick Badge be created for this kind of thing, and for you to be the first to be awarded it.

Comment: Of course, the Mitnick would have to be retroactively awarded to giants on whose shoulders you have stood.

Comment: @George Glad you like it! I've added a narrative of how the search unfolded to my answer. I was glad of your question: it was a fun chance to meander behind the scenes for a bit.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out what "Part" did. I didn't get as far as the selection of the path.  "Part" is in the documentation, as [[ ]], but it's misleading in this context.  So, this function doesn't really drop anything; it extracts the complement of the unwanted dates.

Comment: Regarding the internal functions I would like to add disclaimer "use at your own risk".  If the date is at the end of time range, the observation can be eliminated using `TimeSeriesWindow`. `TimeSeriesDrop` is a valid suggestion though, noted.